# Why should I use Validators.compose()?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular2-formbuilder

I have a field I want to validate with multiple validators.
Using the Module Driven approach the code looks likes this:

```js
this.exampleForm = this.fb.group({
  date_start : [
    '',
    Validators.compose([
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}")
    ])]
})
```

But I can also write this withouth **Validators.compose()** like:

```js
this.exampleForm = this.fb.group({
  date_start : [
    '',
    [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.pattern("[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}")
    ]
  ]
})
```

And it works just fine. Personally I prefer the 2nd version (without **compose**), less code and better readability. And this begs the question, **why should I use Validators.compose()?**

Comment: I guess it's mostly there fore historical reasons.

Comment: Hehe, I guess... It's really weird that I found that historic method everywhere so far (videos, blogs...), and then suddenly on Angular Cookbook I found out I don't need it.

Comment: There was a big rework of the Forms module in July/August 2016, and there the requirement of `compose()` was removed, but I guess they kept it to not unnecessarily break existing code and confuse users.

Comment: Oh, I've figured it would probably be something like that. Well thanks for the info. :)

Comment: Well... it's still necessary to add **multiple** *validators* on FormArray (because its constructor only accepts a single `ValidatorFn` instead of `array`. It won't be necessary only when they merge this [**pull request**](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12763).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When we create `new FormControl/FormGroup/FormArray`(AbstractControl) - `coerceToValidator` is called.

```
function coerceToValidator(
    validatorOrOpts?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | AbstractControlOptions | null): ValidatorFn|
    null {
  const validator =
      (isOptionsObj(validatorOrOpts) ? (validatorOrOpts as AbstractControlOptions).validators :
                                       validatorOrOpts) as ValidatorFn |
      ValidatorFn[] | null;

  return Array.isArray(validator) ? composeValidators(validator) : validator || null;
}

export function composeValidators(validators: Array<Validator|Function>): ValidatorFn|null {
  return validators != null ? Validators.compose(validators.map(normalizeValidator)) : null;
}
```

So there is no need to compose validators before we pass it to an AbstractControl.

6/13/16 was added `feat(forms): compose validator fns automatically if arrays` from now on, Validators.compose is there for backward compatibility.

Comment: Hey. What does `fns` means? Sorry. I did'nt get this abbreviation meaning.

Answer (score 25):

I know this is an old-ish question, but it came up on a recent search.

The main reason you may want to use `Validators.compose()` is to reuse multiple validators. Let's say you want to check that a value is between 0 and 100. The first time, you would write:

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
  foo: [ 0, [ Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100)]]
});
```

Now let's say you want to do that in several places within your app. To avoid code duplication, you would create your own validator by simply composing it from the existing validators, expose it and reuse it everywhere you need:

```js
// custom-validators.ts
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';
export class CustomValidators {
  readonly betweenZeroHundred = Validators.compose([
    Validators.min(0),
    Validators.max(100),
  ]);
}

// form1 
this.form = this.fb.group({
  foo: [ 0, [CustomValidators.betweenZeroHundred()]]
});

// form2
this.form = this.fb.group({
  bar: [ 100, [CustomValidators.betweenZeroHundred()]]
});
```

Nowadays, with the spread operator, you can achieve a similar result, without the `compose()`:

```js
export class CustomValidators {
  readonly betweenZeroHundred = [Validators.min(0), Validators.max(100)];
}

this.form = this.fb.group({
  bar: [ 100, [...CustomValidators.betweenZeroHundred, Validators.required]]
});
```

In the end, it's a matter of which approach is a better fit for your team and your situation.

Comment: Why not just reuse an array throughout the codebase? I see no reason to use the `Validators.compose`.

Comment: That was my first tought as well - just use array.

Comment: I'd just go with arrays and spread operator since it shows clearly whats going on, without navigation back and forth or consulting the docs of another function.