# Validators.required, Validators.email

Tags: angular, typescript, validation

I create form in ts:

```
private _createForm() {
    this.addForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        login: [ null, Validators.required ],
        name: [ null, Validators.required ],
        surname: [ null, Validators.required ],
        email: [ null, Validators.required, Validators.email]
    });
}
```

and in html:

```
...
<forms-validation feedback="Niepoprawny adres email" [dataObj]="addForm ? addForm.controls.email : null" [inputRef]="email">
   <input type="text" name="email" formControlName="email" #email maxlength="{{maxlength}}" class="form-control" LayoutInput />
</forms-validation>
...
```

But validation does not work - required it OK, but email validator does not work.

Answer (score 6):

You need to put validators into sub array.

```
email: [null, [Validators.required, Validators.email]]
              ^                                     ^
```

Comment: Should I use `Validators.compose([...])`?

Comment: Yes, the newer versions use `Validators.compose([...])`

Comment: I just have found out that there is no need to use it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394999/why-should-i-use-validators-compose/52625547.

Answer (score 0):

I find other answer:

```
<input email type="text" name="email" formControlName="email" #email maxlength="{{maxlength}}" class="form-control" LayoutInput />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pattern validator because the email is not working correctly.

```
email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]{2,}[.][A-Za-z]{2,}$')]]
```