# Angular 4, validator says form is invalid

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular4-forms

I want to test the validity of my fields with a simple validator but it keeps saying it's invalid. I don't see any errors in my console either.

In my **component.ts** file:

```
   this.oneClickForm = this.fb.group({
      pwdControl: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7)]],
      pwdControl2: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7)]]

    });

  get pwdControl() {
    return this.oneClickForm.get('pwdControl');
  }
  get pwdControl2() {
    return this.oneClickForm.get('pwdControl2');
  }
```

**My Html:**

```
     <form [formGroup]="oneClickForm">
          <div *ngIf = "showErrors" class="alert alert-danger mb-0 form-errors">
            <span class="block">{{errorMsgOne}}</span>
            <span class="block">{{errorMsgTwo}}</span>
          </div>

       <div *ngIf="showErrors">
          <div *ngIf="pwdControl.hasError('minlength') || pwdControl2.hasError('minlength')"  class="alert alert-danger">
              <span>Password's length must be more than 6 characters</span>
          </div>
        <div *ngIf="pwdControl.hasError('maxlength') || pwdControl2.hasError('maxlength')"  class="alert alert-danger">
          <span>Password's length must be less than 30 characters</span>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="pwdControl.hasError('regexPassword')">
          User name not valid.
     </div>
    </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="createPassword">Create your Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Enter a password" name="pwd" type="password" formControlName="pwdControl" [pattern]="regexPassword">

            <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Don't share your password with anyone! :)</small>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Re-enter Password:</label>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter above password" name="confirmPwd" type="password" formControlName="pwdControl2">
          </div>
          <button [disabled]="isLoading" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4" [disabled] = "!oneClickForm.valid" (click) = "submit(pwd, confirmPwd)">
            <i *ngIf="isLoading" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Submit
        </button>

        </form>

        <p>Form value {{ oneClickForm.value | json }} </p>
        <p> Form status {{ oneClickForm.status | json}} </p>


  </div>
```

I enter 7+ letters in my fields and it says my form is invalid still.  What am I missing?

Comment: I dont see any issue with your code : It works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-forms-amit Only thing is removed extra `</div>` from your code.

Comment: Yes, also looks the same to me, I tried minimizing my code to as much as possible and it still shows up as invalid, not sure why

Comment: try ```pwdControl2: ['' , Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(7)])]``` and check it in html this way : ```oneClickForm.controls.pwdControl2.invalid```

Comment: Do you have any other field added dynamically inside the form?

Comment: @fatemefazli That should not make a difference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394999/why-should-i-use-validators-compose

Comment: I do not, the HTML is the same, the only changes I made were to the TS file but I literally copied pasted what you had in your stackblitz and it still shows up as invalid.