# Validators compose angular seems to be not working

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm trying to validate the user's input with 2 validators with patterns combined with `Validators.compose([])`
But then in HTML I'm trying to validate but it's not working
Here is the code:

component.ts

```
...
searchForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private data: DataSharingService,
    private router: Router
  ){ }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createSearchForm();
    this.newMessage()
  }

  private createSearchForm(): void {
    this.searchForm = new FormGroup({
      emailFormControl: new FormControl('', Validators.compose([
        Validators.pattern['/^[a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9]{6}/'],
        Validators.pattern['/^[0-9]{10}/']
      ]))
    });
  }
...
```

component.html

```html
<form class="mainContainer" [formGroup]="searchForm">
<mat-form-field class="searchfield">
  <input matInput placeholder="Type in tax payer ID or initials " 
        formControlName="emailFormControl"
        i18n-placeholder="@@SearchPeHint">
  <mat-error *ngIf="searchForm.controls['emailFormControl'].hasError('required')" i18n="@@SearchPeParamsRequired">
       Tax payer ID or initials are required!
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don'y have to use `Validators.compose([])`. In mat-error you check `searchForm.controls['emailFormControl'].hasError('required')"` but emailFormControl have no required validator.

[About Validators.compose()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394999/why-should-i-use-validators-compose)