# Angular: Why does my formArray not validate or update?

Tags: angular, typescript, formarray, ng-zorro-antd

I'm trying to get an array of form fields to validate or update on my parent form group.
Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

What I basically want to achieve is to add a new 'Vendor Line' with more than one form field.
And validate each of those fields too. Currently only the formGroup's outer field is validating. I wan't to validate each of the formArray fields too. I'm using ng-zorro framework from Ant, if that helps.
Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

**new-project.component.html**

```html
<div nz-row nzGutter="16">
  <div nz-col>
    <h2>Create new Project</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div nz-row nzGutter="16">
  <div nz-col nzSpan="6" nzOffset="18">
    <button nz-button nzType="primary" nzBlock>
      <i nz-icon nzType="download"></i>Primary
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<form nz-form nzLayout="vertical" [formGroup]="validateForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <div nz-row nzGutter="16">
    <div nz-col nzSpan="6">
      <nz-form-item>
        <nz-form-label>Project Name</nz-form-label>
        <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please enter a project name">
          <input formControlName="projectName" nz-input placeholder="Project Name" />
        </nz-form-control>
      </nz-form-item>
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="6">
      <nz-form-item>
        <nz-form-label>Company Code</nz-form-label>
        <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select a company code" nzHasFeedback>
          <app-company-select formControlName="selectedCompanyValue"></app-company-select>
        </nz-form-control>
      </nz-form-item>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div nz-row nzGutter="16">
    <div nz-col nzSpan="5">
      Vendor
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="4">
      Budget
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="3">
      Available Budget
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="4">
      Budget to use in Project
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="2">
      Currency
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="2">
      Layer 1
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="2">
      Layer 2
    </div>
    <div nz-col nzSpan="2">
      Layer 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div formArrayName="projectHeaders">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let projectHeader of validateForm.get('projectHeaders').controls; let i = index" formGroupName="{{i}}">
      <div nz-row nzGutter="16">
        <div nz-col nzSpan="5">
          <nz-form-item>
            <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select a vendor" nzHasFeedback>
              <app-vendor-search formControlName="selectedVendorValue"></app-vendor-search>
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
        <div nz-col nzSpan="4">
          <nz-form-item>
            <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select a budget" nzHasFeedback>
              <nz-select formControlName="selectedBudgetValue" nzAllowClear nzPlaceHolder="Budgets">
                <nz-option *ngFor="let o of listOfBudgets" [nzLabel]="o.text" [nzValue]="o.value"> </nz-option>
              </nz-select>
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
        <div nz-col nzSpan="3">
          <nz-form-item>
            <nz-form-control>
              <input nz-input placeholder="" formControlName="availableBudget" [disabled]="true" />
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
        <div nz-col nzSpan="4">
          <nz-form-item>
            <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Make sure you have selected a valid budget amount.">
              <nz-input-number formControlName="budgetToUseInProject" [nzFormatter]="parseCurrencyEUR" style="width: 100%;">
              </nz-input-number>
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
        <div nz-col nzSpan="2">
          <nz-form-item>
            <nz-form-control>
              <input nz-input placeholder="" formControlName="currency" [disabled]="true" />
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
        <div nz-col nzSpan="2">
          <nz-form-item>
            <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select a layer" nzHasFeedback>
              <nz-select formControlName="layer1" nzAllowClear nzPlaceHolder="Layer 1">
                <nz-option *ngFor="let o of layerOneOptions" [nzLabel]="o.text" [nzValue]="o.value"> </nz-option>
              </nz-select>
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
        <div nz-col nzSpan="2">
          <nz-form-item>
            <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select a layer" nzHasFeedback>
              <nz-select formControlName="layer2" nzAllowClear nzPlaceHolder="Layer 2">
                <nz-option *ngFor="let o of layerOneTwoOptions" [nzLabel]="o.text" [nzValue]="o.value"> </nz-option>
              </nz-select>
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
        <div nz-col nzSpan="2">
          <nz-form-item>
            <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please select a layer" nzHasFeedback>
              <nz-select formControlName="layer3" nzAllowClear nzPlaceHolder="Layer 3">
                <nz-option *ngFor="let o of layerThreeOptions" [nzLabel]="o.text" [nzValue]="o.value"> </nz-option>
              </nz-select>
            </nz-form-control>
          </nz-form-item>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>
  <!-- <div formArrayName="projectHeaders">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let projectHeader of validateForm.get('projectHeaders').controls; let i = index">
      <app-vendor-line [group]="projectHeader"></app-vendor-line>
    </ng-container>
  </div> -->
  <div nz-row nzGutter="16">
    <div nz-col nzSpan="24">
      <nz-form-item>
        <nz-form-control nzErrorTip="Please">
          <button nz-button nzSize="large" nzType="primary" nzBlock>Primary</button>
        </nz-form-control>
      </nz-form-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**new-project.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { formatNumber } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-project',
  templateUrl: './new-project.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-project.component.css']
})
export class NewProjectComponent implements OnInit {
  validateForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

    this.validateForm = this.fb.group({
      selectedCompanyValue: [null, [Validators.required]],
      projectName: [null, [Validators.required]],
      projectHeaders: this.fb.array([]),
      projectLines: []
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {


    this.addHeaderLine();
  }

  submitForm(): void {
    // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
    for (const i in this.validateForm.controls) {
      this.validateForm.controls[i].markAsDirty();
      this.validateForm.controls[i].updateValueAndValidity();
      if (i === 'projectHeaders') {
        const control = this.validateForm.get('projectHeaders') as FormArray;
        for (const j of control.controls) {
          j.markAsDirty();
          j.updateValueAndValidity();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  initProjectHeader() {
    return this.fb.group({
      selectedVendorValue: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      selectedBudgetValue: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      availableBudget: [{value: 0, disabled: true }, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      budgetToUseInProject: [0, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      currency: [{value: 'EUR', disabled: true}, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      layer1: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      layer2: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
      layer3: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required])]
    });
  }

  addHeaderLine() {
    const control = this.validateForm.controls.projectHeaders as FormArray;
    control.push(this.initProjectHeader());
  }

  parseCurrencyEUR(value: number): string {
    return formatNumber(value, 'de_DE');
  }


}
```

Comment: is it necessary to use validators.compose ?? " 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42394999/why-should-i-use-validators-compose "

Comment: nope, same issue with or without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to figure what the issue is. Apparently you have to even mark the nested forms as dirty and update them so I modified the onSubmit function to do just this. Thanks to all the others who tried to help :)

```
submitForm(): void {
  // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
  for (const i in this.validateForm.controls) {
    this.validateForm.controls[i].markAsDirty();
    this.validateForm.controls[i].updateValueAndValidity();
    if (i === 'projectHeaders') {
      const control = this.validateForm.get('projectHeaders') as FormArray;
      // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
      for (const j in control.controls) {
        const controlTwo = control.controls[j] as FormGroup;
        // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
        for (const k in controlTwo.controls) {
          controlTwo.controls[k].markAsDirty();
          controlTwo.controls[k].updateValueAndValidity();
        }
      }
    }
    if (i === 'projectLines') {
      const control = this.validateForm.get('projectLines') as FormArray;
      // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
      for (const j in control.controls) {
        const controlTwo = control.controls[j] as FormGroup;
        // tslint:disable-next-line: forin
        for (const k in controlTwo.controls) {
          controlTwo.controls[k].markAsDirty();
          controlTwo.controls[k].updateValueAndValidity();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Validators.required`, it will either make form invalid or valid and the field will also become invalid if required is failing. So if it satisfy the condition, it will make form as valid, otherwise invalid. You can put custom validaiton messgae or make the border red and disable the submit button in order to show that the field is required and not allowing to submit

In css:: `input.form-control.ng-invalid {
    border: 2px solid red;
}` 
Your ts file is good. Just need to add validation message or making field border red in case required is not satisfied.

Comment: If you find this answer suitable as per your requirement, please accept this answer as well.

Comment: Hi Sudeep this, however wasn't what I was looking for. I however found what I was doing wrong.